# Yesod Installation unable to load package `foundation-0.0.10'

Tags: haskell, yesod, haskell-stack

Trying to get Yesod set up on Windows 7. I have been following the guide here http://www.yesodweb.com/page/quickstart. I skipped step 1 as I already have stack installed.

After step 3 - "Install the yesod command line tool: stack build yesod-bin cabal-install --install-ghc" the console said a Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1.

The log that it directed me to had the following contents:

```
Configuring yesod-bin-1.5.2.3...
Building yesod-bin-1.5.2.3...
Preprocessing executable 'yesod' for yesod-bin-1.5.2.3...
[1 of 7] Compiling Paths_yesod_bin  ( .stack-work\dist\ca59d0ab\build\autogen\Paths_yesod_bin.hs, .stack-work\dist\ca59d0ab\build\yesod\yesod-tmp\Paths_yesod_bin.o )
[2 of 7] Compiling Options          ( Options.hs, .stack-work\dist\ca59d0ab\build\yesod\yesod-tmp\Options.o )
[3 of 7] Compiling Keter            ( Keter.hs, .stack-work\dist\ca59d0ab\build\yesod\yesod-tmp\Keter.o )
[4 of 7] Compiling HsFile           ( HsFile.hs, .stack-work\dist\ca59d0ab\build\yesod\yesod-tmp\HsFile.o )
[5 of 7] Compiling Devel            ( Devel.hs, .stack-work\dist\ca59d0ab\build\yesod\yesod-tmp\Devel.o )
ghc.EXE: unable to load package `foundation-0.0.10'
ghc.EXE: C:\sr\snapshots\f4677c28\lib\x86_64-windows-ghc-8.0.2\foundation-0.0.10-JGhHXvcRrtp6mVId9fjHXB\HSfoundation-0.0.10-JGhHXvcRrtp6mVId9fjHXB.o: unknown symbol `clock_gettime'
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I think this is a bug with either `foundation` or even GHC - I distinctly remember `yesod` and friends working on older versions of GHC (but now I can confirm that `foundation` produces this linker error on 8.0). Your best bet is probably to try an older version or to report the bug.

Comment: @user2407038 Ok, do I just need to uninstall GHC and install version 8.0 or do I also need to add some version numbers somewhere in the commands from the quickstart guide?

Comment: With stack, you specify this in your projects [`stack.yaml` file](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/v1.0.2/yaml_configuration/#resolver). (Note that ghc 8.0 is the version that *has* the error. You will want at most 7.10.3)

Comment: Alternatively, add `memory-0.14.2` to your `stack.yaml` file. [This](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/memory-0.14.3) appears to be the (only) package which pulls in the broken `foundation` dependency - `yesod` does not depend on it directly. Also you probably need `stack install yesod-bin --ghc-options "--constraint=memory<0.14.3"` as well as the setting in the `stack.yaml` file. This should allow you to use any GHC you want.

Comment: @user2407038 ok thanks, I'm currently trying ghc version 7.10.3.

Comment: @user2407038 I tried both options you gave however I get loads of messages like this https://gyazo.com/213019decb3123f06690ad9acb475280

Comment: Try checking out the `stack` documentation for any errors which come from `stack` itself - it is pretty well documented. (For that error, probably `stack solver` but a single line of an error is not much to go on).

Comment: @user2407038 the console kept telling me to add various dependencies to the stack.yaml file so I did, eventually I got down to just this error `Error: While constructing the build plan, the following exceptions were encounte
red:

In the dependencies for cabal-install-1.24.0.2:
    Cabal-1.22.5.0 must match >=1.24.2 && <1.25 (latest applicable is 1.24.2.0)`

Comment: Hi James! The following is contrary to what 99% of people will recommend. I personally avoid stack: there's too much magic going on behind the scenes for my taste, and when there's an error like that I get stuck. I think that should *never* happen, especially to a beginner. Just so that you can get started asap: with GHC 7.10.3 and cabal 1.24, just doing `cabal sandbox init` and then `cabal install yesod --reorder-goals` in a new directory works for me. I can compile the hello world in the 'Basics' chapter with `cabal exec -- ghc Example.hs` and it runs fine.